# Python 3 - create combination of list within dictionary and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, combinations

I think I'm going about this all in a backwards way in pandas.  Here's an example dataframe:

```
Group rstart rend  qty
1     10000  11000 1000
1     10000  11000 8000
1     10000  11000 13000
1     10000  11000 1000
2     6000   8000  4000
2     6000   8000  9000
2     6000   8000  3000
```

In the end I'm trying to identify the quantity or combination of quantities within the group that fall between the range and put a flag in a new column (and if possible save the combination in a new column too).

Here's what I have done so far and where I'm running into an issue - been trying out all different ways since I'm new to this language.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
d = df[['group','qty']]
s = d.groupby('group')['qty'].apply(list).to_dict()
comb = list(map(dict,itertools.combinations(s.items(),2)))
```

The comb stmt and multiple variations I tried are just printing the dictionary. Put 2 for two variations to test it out but not working - this would have to be adjusted based on the # of values in the list.

I brought in the dataset and then was thinking it would be best to create a dictionary with a list for each grouping and qty in order to create all the combinations in a separate table.  Once I have the combinations and sum of each of the values - link back to the main dataframe to compare against total and flag.

I'm running into issues with creating each combination of the quantities associated with the group and summing. I can perform it if stored in a list across all dictionaries but I need to grouped by the group. For instance, group 1 should have   1000,8000 and 1000,13000 and  1000,1000 and 1000,8000,13000 and so on. The amount of combinations can vary by group.

Can anyone assist with guiding me in the right direction? Maybe my thinking is off on how to go about this.

Thank you

Comment: I don't not understand your requirements. For example, why is 1000,13000, and 1000 in the range 10000 - 11000?

Comment: They aren't when looked at alone - I'm trying to figure out if the the qty or the combination of the quantities within that group are within that range. In that group the 1000,8000 and 1000 should be identified since they sum to within that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one self explanatory solution which also uses `itertools.combination` in conjunction with list comprehensions:

```
def aggregate(sub_df):
    # get boundaries and actual values 
    bound_low = sub_df["rstart"].iloc[0]
    bound_high = sub_df["rend"].iloc[0]
    values = sub_df["qty"].values

    # get possible combinations, iterate all lengths of combinations
    combis = [itertools.combinations(values, x+1)
              for x in range(len(values))]

    # flatten all combis and apply filter condition
    result = [combi for sub_combi in combis 
              for combi in sub_combi 
              if bound_low <= sum(combi) <= bound_high]

    return result

print(df.groupby("Group").apply(aggregate))

Group
1    [(1000, 8000, 1000)]
2          [(4000, 3000)]
dtype: object
```

However, I don't understand your `group 1 should have 1000,8000 and 1000,13000 and 1000,1000 and 1000,8000,13000` here.

Comment: Thank you very much pansen.  I'm going to go through your solution to make sure I understand everything etc I just wrote that out showing an example of the combinations that needed to be created for group 1. The output from your logic is correct.